# Laravel 5.2 reset password with another column name (not email)

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm taking over a project from the other, the old database schema uses "username" instead of "email". It causes the conflict when I add reset password functionality.

```
public function getEmailForPasswordReset()
{
    return $this->email;
}
```

Is there some way to customize that trait to use another column name over "email"?

Comment: and how are u gonna send the reset link if u don't wanna use email?

Comment: I mean the old version used email to login with column name is email. So if you want to get email, just access to username :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this way?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#renaming-columns

Rename the old column to `email`. It's a lot better for the future rather than making a new attribute from the old column :)

Comment: Ya, it's also a good way. But I'm afraid of changing column name directly, what's about old function which is using old schema? :D

Comment: That's why you have development environment so you won't worry about anything. Just try, backup your data. If it fails, try anything else. Keeping old schema isn't future proof, and make cause amazing confusion for another developer on your company in the future (WHAAAT, THERE'S NO EMAIL COLUMN HERE. WHAAAAAAAAAAAAAT DAFREEEEEAAAAK. Oh dang, this guy just adding an accessor rather than changing the column name. gosh. I'll do it myself). Remember simple rule: Always code like another developer that will read your code is a psychopath that knows where you live. :)

Comment: "Always code like another developer that will read your code is a psychopath that knows where you live"
I love it, thank you. :D

Answer (score 0):

I add a new accessor to User Model:

```
public function getEmailAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['username'];
}
```

Hope someone got similar issues could use it. Welcome to better solution.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Where will the password reset email get sent if you are overriding the email field?

Comment: There is no email field in database, the user_name is all I have, so instead of change column name, I give one accessor to retrieve data.

Comment: But the email address is required to send password reset email with unique link. Unless the username column actually contains email addresses then your solution won't work.

Comment: Yes, Niraj, that's exact what username contains. :D